# Is cache condition necessary to stop HTML being inserted into database cache?

Tags: cache

We currently use cache tags with a condition referencing the `cache` config setting:

```
{% cache for 1 hour if craft.config.cache %}
```

Is the condition necessary to stop HTML being inserted into the database cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is a better way to do this. Set the `enableTemplateCaching` [config value](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#enableTemplateCaching) to false.

```
'enableTemplateCaching' => false,
```

With that setting disabled, all caching will be skipped.

```
// Won't be cached
{% cache for 1 hour %}
```